# Query plan & perf. variations on another machine

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm not a PostgreSQL expert, and I've been struggling with this.

I have a rather simple query:

```
SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM res_users_log WHERE create_uid=u.id), count(1)
FROM res_users u
WHERE active=true
GROUP BY 1
```

Basically it counts the number of active users that have a log entry. Both tables are relatively big (~600k records each) and have indexes on their ids.

This query executes in ~500ms on our server, but completely hangs on my machine (same psql version, 9.3). My database is a restore of the server's dump so the indexes have been reindexed on import.

When I do an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query, I get different results on the server and on my machine.

Locally I get

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=78496.43..88302.28 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=518.003..518.003 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using res_users_pkey on res_users u  (cost=0.42..78496.35 rows=16 width=4) (actual time=51.393..517.969 rows=11 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id < 20)
         Filter: active
         Rows Removed by Filter: 7
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Seq Scan on res_users_log  (cost=0.00..9805.83 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=47.078..47.078 rows=1 loops=11)
                 Filter: (create_uid = u.id)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 516910
 Total runtime: 518.034 ms
(10 rows)
```

(had to add the id < 20 to have the query actually finish)

and on the server I get

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=5389666981.78..5389687409.80 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=532.664..532.665 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on res_users u  (cost=0.00..5389664343.42 rows=527672 width=4) (actual time=256.169..467.829 rows=527661 loops=1)
         Filter: active
         Rows Removed by Filter: 381
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Seq Scan on res_users_log  (cost=0.00..10214.00 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
                 Filter: (create_uid = u.id)
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Seq Scan on res_users_log res_users_log_1  (cost=0.00..8800.60 rows=565360 width=4) (actual time=0.006..45.697 rows=547108 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 532.757 ms
(10 rows)
```

I've been trying to determine why the query plans are different (and I don't understand the SubPlan 2 entry) and what could possibly make this query take more than 2hrs (killed it after that) on my laptop...

I've vacuumed both tables without any noticeable difference.

Any ideas of what could make this hang like that?

Comment: local and server data is different

Comment: Does that query really do what you want?  I would think the first column would always be true or false, so it is not a count.

Comment: @MaxP. nope, I use the dump of the test server, a few records might have changed in the last 4 hours but I would guess not to the point of breaking the query

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query returns two rows, (t & f) with t being the number of users that have a log entry

Comment: @DamienB. You are very wrong.`EXISTS (ABC)` always yields a boolean value. (but only if ABC is a valid (sub)query, of course)

Comment: @wildplasser Indeed, that's what I mean. I obtain two rows, true or false (the result of exists), and the count() that goes with each; so i know the number of users where a log exists and the number where it doesn't

Comment: My guess is that the server has a warmed-up cache, and a larger setting for work_mem. In both cases, there doesm't seem to be a usable index for user_log. {user_id, created_at} appears to be a logical candidate. (but you didn't show us your table definition or data distribution)

Answer (score 0):

If you want active users that have a log entry, I would expect:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM res_users u
WHERE u.active = true and
      exists (SELECT 1 FROM res_users_log l WHERE l.create_uid = u.id);
```

Then indexes on `res_users(active, id)` and `res_users_log(create_uid)` would be optimal.

Comment: Thanks, the query works correctly. However I would have liked to know why the difference in query plan occured... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't really solve my problem; I need the group by (I know I could do the obivous `not exists` complementary query, but I really would like to understand what's going on here).